# Avoid HttpWebRequest GET and ProtocolViolationException

Tags: httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient, http-protocols

Is there anyway to prevent `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` from throwing an exception when the method is `GET`? I know that `HEAD` and `GET` should not contain a body in valid HTTP, but some servers accept bodies for these methods anyway (e.g., Elasticsearch's `_search` feature). I have an open source project for doing REST calls and I was wondering if I could circumvent this behavior to avoid surprises.

At some point, I will probably create a version of my library using the new `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class. Does this class have the same restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core 2.0:

`System.Net.Http.HttpClient` (Version=4.2.0.0) does not have this restriction if you use the `SendAsync` method.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://example.com/api/_search");
request.Content = new StringContent(jsonSearchCriteria, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request,
    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```